# Azure tomcat app does't start Process '5384' failed to start. Port = 21220, Error Code = '-2147023829'

Tags: azure

I have a `tomcat` app on `azure` for several months now. It's been working well but for the past couple of hours I can't redeploy. My `.war` file is in its proper location inside `webapps` but no `ROOT` directory is created and the app is not available.

In the `Event Log` I see that the app fails to start. Any idea how to fix this?

This is the full log (there are several such entries in the log, one for each of my attempts at restarting):

```
<Event>
 <System>
  <Provider Name="HttpPlatformHandler"/>
  <EventID>1000</EventID>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Task>0</Task>
  <Keywords>Keywords</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-03-27T15:30:56Z"/>
  <EventRecordID>1368052437</EventRecordID>
  <Channel>Application</Channel>
  <Computer>RD000D3A61018F</Computer>
  <Security/>
 </System>
 <EventData>
 <Data>
   Process '5384' failed to start. Port = 21220, Error Code = '-2147023829'.
 </Data>
```

Comment: The problem just disappeared. Probably a glitch in Azure.

Comment: Anyone have ANY idea what this error code is? i'm getting it as well

Comment: Are you deploying to a virtual directory in the web app? https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1147

Comment: Started happening to me after I added web.config to the wwwroot directory.  Probably did not configure it correctly.  Troubleshooting.

Comment: OK yes, it was invalid configuration of the web.config file.  JAVA_OPTS environment variable had too high of memory being set: max allowed for Xmx turned out to be 768m, and max for PermSize was 64m.   Ended up not needed Perm after switching to Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by the invalid configuration of the web.config file in wwwroot directory.

In my case, the issue was that I set memory too high the JAVA_OPTS environment variable.  After trial and error with various values I found that for my app service max allowed Xmx was 768m, and max PermSize had to be 64m.